# Is there a way to reuse one observable until second will get onComplete() in zip?

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I have one observable with a list of String and another with a list of string lists.
I need to reuse first observable until every string is stetted

In short. I need to iterate through every element of the list's list and attach it to first observable list elements

I learned about retryWhen but don't know how to reuse first observable and continue on the second

```
val cat = sheetsViewer.GOOGLE_SHEETS_ENDPOINT_IMPL.readSpreadSheet(spreadsheetId, "A4:DA4")
            .toObservable()
            .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }


val data = sheetsViewer.GOOGLE_SHEETS_ENDPOINT_IMPL.readSpreadSheet(spreadsheetId, range)
            .toObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
            .map {
                val newList = it.toMutableList()

                while (newList.size != 105)
                    newList.add("")

                return@map newList
            }
```

I have list of strings {"a", "b"}
and second {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}}

I expect the output to be {"aa", "bb", "ca", "db", "ea", "fb"}

Comment: Try replacing `zip` with `combineLatest`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Flowable<List<String>> listOfStrings = Flowable.fromIterable(asList(asList("a", "b"),
                                                                       asList("c", "d"),
                                                                       asList("e", "f")));
    final Flowable<String> strings = Flowable.fromIterable(asList("a", "b"));

    listOfStrings.flatMap(list -> Flowable.zip(Flowable.fromIterable(list),
                                               strings,
                                              (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2))
                 .subscribe(System.out::println,
                            System.err::println);

    Flowable.timer(10, SECONDS) // Just to block the main thread for a while
            .blockingSubscribe();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean with "reuse". If it means that you want to subscribe on the first observable only once, then you can do the following (based on your example):

```
fun main() {
    val listOfStringsObs = listOf("a", "b").toObservable()
    val listOfListOfStringsObs = listOf(
        listOf("a", "b"),
        listOf("c", "d"),
        listOf("e", "f")
    ).toObservable()

    listOfStringsObs
        .toList() // transforming Observable<String> to Single<List<String>> so we could subscribe on the single only once and then reuse the value
        .flatMapObservable { listOfStrings ->
            listOfListOfStringsObs
                .flatMap { element ->
                    element
                        .zip(listOfStrings) { a, b -> a + b } // zipping listOfStrings with each element from listOfListOfStrings by concatenating the strings
                        .toObservable()
                }
        }
        .subscribe(
            { println("Data: $it") },
            { println("Error: $it") },
            { println("Done") }
        )
}
```